# How to find 5 closest number from matrix having attributes?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix as follows

```
`> y
       1         2         3
1  0.8802216 1.2277843 0.6875047
2  0.9381081 1.3189847 0.2046542
3  1.3245534 0.8221709 0.4630722
4  1.2006974 0.8890464 0.6710844
5  1.2344071 0.8354292 0.7259998
6  1.1670665 0.9214787 0.6826173
7  0.9670581 1.1070461 0.7742342
8  0.8867365 1.2160533 0.7024281
9  0.8235792 1.4424190 0.2030302
10 0.8821301 1.0541099 1.2279813
11 1.1958634 0.9708839 0.4297043
12 1.3542734 0.7747481 0.5119648
13 0.4385487 0.3588158 4.9167998
14 0.8530141 1.3578511 0.3698620
15 0.9651803 0.8426226 1.6132899
16 0.8854192 1.2272616 0.6715839
17 0.7779642 0.8132233 2.3386331
18 0.9936722 1.1629110 0.5083558
19 1.1235897 1.0018480 0.5764672
20 0.7887222 1.3101684 0.7373181
21 2.2276176 0.0000000 0.0000000`
```

I found one clue, but it can give position for the whole matrix,`

> n<-read.table(file.choose(),header=T)
>
> y<-n[,c("1","2","3")]
>
> my.number=1.12270420185886 .
>
> z<-abs(y-my.number)==min(abs(y-my.number))
> which(z)
> [1] 19 `

I want to find at least the 5 closest values with letter &  column no too, in another way, I want the 5 closest single values from the matrix with their position.

Comment: Is this matlab? Please tag the post to indicate the language

Comment: Are the last two values of 0.0 part of the matrix, or is (21,1) the last value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what language it is; is it R?

In a procedural language, I would save all values to a map (val, (pos)) = (val (row, col); example (0.880..-> (1, 1)), then sort by value.

Then iterate over i<-pos (1 to map.size-5), and get the diff (pos (i), pos (i+5)), search for the minimum (diff), get the values and their position then.

Here is a solution in Scala:

```
val matrix = """1  0.8802216 1.2277843 0.6875047
2  0.9381081 1.3189847 0.2046542
3  1.3245534 0.8221709 0.4630722
4  1.2006974 0.8890464 0.6710844
5  1.2344071 0.8354292 0.7259998
6  1.1670665 0.9214787 0.6826173
7  0.9670581 1.1070461 0.7742342
8  0.8867365 1.2160533 0.7024281
9  0.8235792 1.4424190 0.2030302
10 0.8821301 1.0541099 1.2279813
11 1.1958634 0.9708839 0.4297043
12 1.3542734 0.7747481 0.5119648
13 0.4385487 0.3588158 4.9167998
14 0.8530141 1.3578511 0.3698620
15 0.9651803 0.8426226 1.6132899
16 0.8854192 1.2272616 0.6715839
17 0.7779642 0.8132233 2.3386331
18 0.9936722 1.1629110 0.5083558
19 1.1235897 1.0018480 0.5764672
20 0.7887222 1.3101684 0.7373181
21 2.2276176 0.0000000 0.0000000"""

// split block of text into lines
val lines=matrix.split ("\n")
// split lines into words
val rows = lines.map (l => l.split (" \\+"))
// remove the index from the beginning (1, 2, ... 21) and 
// transform values from Strings to double numbers
// triples is: Array(Array(0.8802216, 1.2277843, 0.6875047), Array(0.9381081, 1.3189847, 0.2046542),
val triples = rows.map (_.tail).map(triple=> triple.map (_.toDouble))
// generate an own index for the rows and columns 
// elems is: elems: Array[Array[(Double, (Int, Int))]] = Array(Array((0.8802216,(0,0)), (1.2277843,(0,1)), (0.6875047,(0,2))), Array((0.9381081,(1,0)), ...
val elems = triples.zipWithIndex.map {t=> t._1.zipWithIndex.map (vc=> (vc._1 -> (t._2, vc._2)))}
// sorted = Array((0.0,(20,1)), (0.0,(20,2)), (0.2030302,(8,2)), (0.2046542,(1,2)), 
val sorted = elems.sortBy (e => e._1)
// delta5 = List(0.3588158, 0.369862, 0.2266741, 0.2338945, 0.10425639999999997, 0.1384938,
val delta5 = sorted.sliding (5, 1).map (q => q(4)._1-q(0)._1).toList
val minindex = delta5.indexOf (delta5.min) // minindex: Int = 29, delta5.min = 0.008824799999999966

// we found the smallest intervall of 5 values beginning at 29: 
(29 to 29 +5).map (sorted (_)) 
res568: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Double, (Int, Int))] = 
    Vector( (0.8802216,(0,0)), 
        (0.8821301,(9,0)), 
        (0.8854192,(15,0)), 
        (0.8867365,(7,0)), 
        (0.8890464,(3,1)), 
        (0.9214787,(5,1)))
```

Since Scala counts from 0 to 20 and 0 to 2, where your index runs from 1 to 3 and 1 to 21 respectively, you have to add (1,1) to each of the positions=> (1,1), (10,1), and so on.

Comment: Yes sir i am using R language,can u transform code in R,as i dont know scala(i find difficult to decode it & find similar function in R)

Comment: @SagarNikam: I added some remarks to the code, since I have nearly no experience with R. Can you just sort all the values in y, search for the smallest interval between 5 elements and find those elements, covered by the interval, in y again? I guess you can't translate the algorithm stepwise.